# Problems with PyQt signals

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I've developed an application with python using PyQt4 libraries.

Well, I have a lot of "connections" to start a method of one class when, for example, a method of another one finishes(e.g. `self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('some_signal(QString, QString)'), string1, string2)`).

So, when I launch a signal (like the one in the last paragraph) in the init method of the class it gets ignored. But if I create a button and then connect this button to a method, and within this method I launch the signal, it works.

Can anybody explain me why and give me a solution to launch the signal in the init method of the class.

Thanks in advance!!

Adria

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stack overflow. As it stands, your questions is impossible to answer without more information, and is likely to be closed unless you edit it and provide more information. Please see the help centre for [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, **importantly**, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a signal from the `__init__` method works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    mySignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        print "START - Emit signal from __init__"
        self.mySignal.emit()
        print "END - Emit signal from __init__"

    def initUI(self):
        self.mySignal.connect(self.print_signal)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Emit signal')
        self.show()


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.mySignal.emit()

    def print_signal(self):
        print "Signal emitted"

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I already solved it, the problem was that I was emitting the signal before of instantiating the connection, then my signal wasn't connected to anything in the moment I emitted it. Then I just copied the signal emitting line after all signal connections were declared and it worked fine as I expected. Thanks for your interest!